# Sum up observations from data frame in R (multiple conditions)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm currently facing the following issue and would highly appreciate any help. My data frame looks like this

```
country_birth   year    migrants   live_in                gender
Albania         2000      1        Australia           male
Germany         2000      2        Australia           female
Albania         2008      3        Australia           male
Albania         2000      6        Australia           female
Germany         2004      2        Australia           female
UK               2004      2         Germany           female
US               2004      5          UK                male
```

Now I would like to get the **sum of migrants (both gender)** for the **same country of birth** and the **same live_in country** for a **matching year**. A new dataframe should look something like this

```
country_birth   year    total_migrants   live_in                
Albania         2000      7              Australia           
...             ...      ...                ...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `aggregate` + `subset` like below

```
> aggregate(migrants ~ ., subset(df, select = -gender), sum)
  country_birth year   live_in migrants
1       Albania 2000 Australia        7
2       Germany 2000 Australia        2
3       Germany 2004 Australia        2
4       Albania 2008 Australia        3
5            UK 2004   Germany        2
6            US 2004        UK        5
```

where

- `subset` omits the columns `gender`
- `aggregate` helps you aggregate `migrants`, grouped by all other columns.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  count(country_birth, year, live_in, wt = migrants, name = "total_migrants")


# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   country_birth  year live_in   total_migrants
#   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
# 1 Albania        2000 Australia              7
# 2 Albania        2008 Australia              3
# 3 Germany        2000 Australia              2
# 4 Germany        2004 Australia              2
# 5 UK             2004 Germany                2
# 6 US             2004 UK                     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the {dplyr} approach:

```
data %>%
  group_by(country_birth, year, live_in) %>%
  summarise(total_migrants = sum(total_migrants))
```

You can learn more about grouped summaries by reading the [dplyr documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) or at [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise).